# How to create a zabbix problem whenever a cisco switch interface utilizes more than 80 mbps (80% of it's bandwidth)

Tags: networking, snmp, zabbix, cisco-ios

I'm trying to create a trigger in zabbix which will show me a problem and alert me on my email whenever an interface in a cisco switch (with snmpv2) crosses 80% of it's bandwidth (100 mbps or 1000 mbps) without hardcoding anything, I tried using this trigger expression:

`{/switch name:net.if.out[ifHCOutOctets./switch interface].min(10)}>80000000`

I would like to know how can I write this trigger expression which works fine without applying it to every single interface item in every switch. I think that maybe macros could help in these situations but found no explanation or any guide about how to use them or how to use low level discovery which maybe have a part at the solution for my need.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies, I actually checked again the Template Module Interfaces SNMPv2 and saw that there is a prototype trigger that solves my question.

for anyone who wants to do the same with a switch:

1. Add to your switch (host) the "Template Module Interfaces SNMPv2" template.
2. Change the IF_UTIL_MAX macro to whatever value you want it to be, the default is 90 (this is the macro which is responsible for the percentage of the bandwidth which will trigger a problem, for example, if you change it to 60, when a host bandwidth utilization averages more than 60% in any interface for 15 minutes, a problem will be added to the problems tab or to the dashboard).
3. If the time of 15 minutes isn't right for you, you can change it by going to: configuration -> templates -> Template Module Interfaces SNMPv2 -> Discovery rules -> Network Interfaces Discovery -> Trigger prototypes -> search for a trigger name which contains high bandwidth usage -> in the problem expression and the recovery expression find the .avg() function and change the value inside it to whatever value is right for you, for an example: 15m = 15 minutes, 1s = 1 second etc...

I actually recommend to clone the trigger prototype, change it and then disable the built in one instead of just changing the time inside it for easily debugging errors in the long run. So you can change the name of the trigger prototype and then clone it by pressing clone in the bottom left corner of the screen, then change it's name and settings for whatever suits you the best.

3. Press add in the bottom left corner of the screen and if you took my advice you also need to click on the green "Yes" link of the built in trigger in the trigger prototypes table for it to disable.

You can also go ahead and try the other answers on this thread, I'm seriously thankful for them but I don't have enough time to check if those work since I already figured it out after reading Simone Zabberoni's and helllordkb's answers and checking the built in low level discovery in the "Template Module Interfaces SNMPv2" template.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you want to use Low Level Discovery to do this, as well as to discover all your interfaces. Low level discovery at a high level consists of two things. 1) you have to tell zabbix how to go discovery a bunch of dynamic things and asssign a LLD macro to them, that is done a the high level of the Discovery rule. 2) you have to tell zabbix what item protototypes, trigger protorypes, etc to dynamically create as actual items and triggers, every time the discovery rule runs.

Take a look at the Arista SNMPv2 template included with zabbix as an example. There are a number of Discovery Rules included in that template, one of which is the Network Interfaces discovery rule. Within the network interfaces discovery rule, zabbix basically does an snmp walk and gets a list of all the interfaces and assigns LLD(Low level discovery macros) for each interfaces such as #IFINDEX, #IFSTATUS, etc. The discovery Rule, like all LLD rules, takes the output of the "Network Interfaces" discovery rule, and uses them to dynamically create actual items on each host the template applied to.

The next part of this to understand is the prototypes. Once zabbbix finds all the network interfaces, your question should be, how do i get it to create new Items in my host for each interface it finds, and how do i get it to create triggers for each interface it finds dynamically, automatically and without user intervention. The answer is protoyptes. Prototypes are child elements of a Low Level Discovery. They are what actually creates the new items and triggers for every thing it discovered.

Take a look here for some examples and docs on low level discovery rules.
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#trigger_prototypes

Zabbix can create LLD rules via numerous discovery methods including SNMPv#, which is all capable of being configured in the UI or api, and other customer discovery rules not included through the use of user parmaters, externel checks, etc.

If your make and model of switch is already known to zabbix, a template in "Templates/Network Devices", at least i think thats the path, will exist just like the arista and juniper ones.

You can create custom low level discovery rules as well for non snmp stuff. basically you write a script that will go find the things you want to dynamically add to zabbix and your script needs to return a valid json output with #macronames and values you want added. For example a custom file system discovery rules, which shouldn't be needed because there already included if your using the agent, would produce lines like the ones shown in this example in the official docs.
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#creating_custom_lld_rules

In short, check to see if a template exists for your switch already and a discovery rule with the item prototypes to discover things the way you want them already. LLD basically allows zabbix too walk a dynamic data structure of any source, as long as that data structure has a definition known to zabbix, and you tell it what keys and values in the JSON you want to create as items, triggers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage the [low level discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery) feature of Zabbix.

After a standard setup you should have a "Template Module Interfaces SNMPv2", which is used by some other templates as a standard for interface discovery.

Within the template you will find a "Network Interfaces Discovery" discovery rule that runs every hour to:

- query the target device for an interface list
- create N items **for each interface** (bits in, bits out, speed, type etc), defined as Item Prototypes
- create some triggers, defined as Trigger Prototypes

The speed item is the negotiated interface speed (ie: 1000 for a gigabit switch port), which is your 100% limit.

You can add some definitions to this template to get the alert you need:

- Create a [calculated](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated) item prototype and set its formula to
  `100*(currentOutputBits/speed)`
- Create a template macro to define your alert threshold, ie `{$INTERFACE_OUTPUT_THRESHOLD}`, and set it to 80
- Create a trigger prototype that matches when the calculated item is
  greater than `{$INTERFACE_OUTPUT_THRESHOLD}` for N minutes
- Optionally, do the same for the currentInputBits item

This setup will create 1 additional item and 1 additional trigger for each physical or logical interface found on the target device: it makes sense to unflag the "create enable" option on the trigger prototype and enable it only on specific ports of specific devices.

The threshold macro can be changed at template level, affecting any device linked to it, or at host level for a custom threshold.